# Where am I going wrong integrating $\int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx$ by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, chain-rule

I was helping a friend with homework and was given the fairly straightforward integral:
$$\int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx$$
The answer the homework checker accepts as correct baffles me since it has one term with one independent degree:

$$\frac1{105}(x^3-6)^{35}+ C$$

That in no way whatsoever resembles my answer:

$$(x^3-6)^{34}(1/3x^3) - \frac {17}{21} x^{42} + \frac {102}{19} x^{38} + C$$

I feel like there is some weird trick that allows us to avoid integrating by parts, but they wanted us to use integration by parts with $u=x^3-6$. These are the steps I used:
$$
\begin{align}
&u = x^3 - 6\\
&w = u^{34}\\
&\frac {d}{dx} w = \frac {dw}{du} \frac {du}{dx} dx\\
&\cdots = (34u^{33})(3x^2)dx = 102x^{38} - 612x^{35}\\
&dv = x^2 dx\\
&v = 1/3 x^3 + C\\
&I = wv - \int v dw\\
&\cdots= (x^3-6)^{34}(1/3x^3) - I_2\\
&I_2 = \int (1/3 x^3)(102x^{38} - 612x^{35}) dx
\end{align}$$

Regardless of anything else, I can't figure out how you are supposed to have $1$ term with one degree, $35$, in our answer.

---

EDIT: Just adding what made the accepted answer make sense to me, $$x^2 u^{34} dx = C(u^{34} du)$$ where $C$ is a constant because I wanted to emphasize the general form.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format mathematical expressions in MathJax.

Comment: Thanks I'll reformat

Comment: $(34u^{33})(3x^2)\mathrm dx = 102\, x^2\, (x^3-6)^{33}\,\mathrm dx\qquad\color{red}\neq 102x^{38}−612x^{35}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration by parts is hardly needed.

We can use substitution: Let $u = (x^3 - 6)$.  So $du = 3x^2\,dx$. Given $$\int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx = \frac 13 \int 3x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx,$$
under substitution, the integral becomes
$$\frac 13\int u^{34} du.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Actually sorry I am having trouble getting between two of your steps. I am not convinced 3x^2 (x^3-6)^34 equals u^34 dx due to the polynomial expansion of u^34, I think it is x^2 u^34

Comment: It equals $\frac 13\int  u^{34} du.$   Suggestion: what is $\frac d{dx} (x^3-6)?$  Note it is equal to $3x^2$.

Comment: ok I think I see now thank you, you're saying x^2 u^34 dx = u^34 du, got it, thank you, should have waited for your edit

Comment: Note that with the substitution, you end up with $$\frac 13\left( \frac {u^{35}}{35}\right) + C. $$  Now back substitute $u = (x^3-6).$

Comment: Thank you again, it turned out she hadn't even been taught integration by parts yet, and I was too lazy to look for the other identity of du and just sort of mechanically went after the way I am used to doing this sort of thing. To make it worse the book had other demo problems in this form. I would never have seen it without your help, thanks again.

Comment: Very glad to have helped out!

Answer (score 5):

> $$\int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx$$

> but they wanted us to use integration by parts with u=x^3-6.

I certainly agree with amwhy's answer.  Integration by parts is an unnecessary complication, since the $u = \left(x^3 - 6\right)$ substitution implies (**informally**) that $du = 3x^2 dx.$

However, this begs the question: what was the problem composer's intended solution, under the assumption that you (**somehow**) combine $u = (x^3 - 6)$ with integration by parts?

So, I will take a crack at what the problem composer might have intended.

For convenience, I will omit displaying any *constants of integration*.

I will use the idea that

$$\left(\int a ~db\right) = ab - \left(\int b ~da\right). \tag1 $$

Set $\displaystyle I = \int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx.$

Set $u = (x^3 - 6).$

Set $a = u^{34}.$ 
Set $db = x^2~dx.$

Then, $\displaystyle I = \int a ~db.$

Following the formula in (1) above,

$\displaystyle I = ab - \int b ~da.$

Since $a = u^{34},$ you have that $da = 34u^{33} du.$

Since $db = x^2 ~dx$, you have that

$$b = \frac{x^3}{3} = \frac{1}{3} (u + 6). \tag2 $$

---

**Edit**
I think that arguments could be made, either way that:

- This whole approach is daffy, and a substitution attempt should be your first try.  Then, integration by parts would not be used for this problem.
- In rebuttal, in addition to reinforcing the correct use of integration by parts, you have that the new Math student is **accidentally** discovering the convenient result in (2) above, by the pedestrian method of integration by parts.  So, there is the suggestion that if an integration problem does not seem to immediately bend to a substitution, that integration by parts might reveal an insight.

---

So, $\displaystyle I = u^{34}\left[\frac{1}{3} (u + 6)\right] - J
 ~=~ \left[\frac{u^{35}}{3} + 2u^{34}\right] - J$,

where $\displaystyle J = \int 34u^{33}\left[\frac{1}{3} (u + 6)\right] ~du = \int \left[\frac{34u^{34}}{3} + 68u^{33}\right] ~du.$

You have that $~\displaystyle 
J = \frac{34u^{35}}{105} + 2u^{34}.$

Therefore,

$~\displaystyle I = \left[\frac{u^{35}}{3} + 2u^{34}\right] - 
\left[\frac{34u^{35}}{105} + 2u^{34}\right] = \frac{u^{35}}{105}
 ~=~ \frac{(x - 6)^{(35)}}{105}.$

Comment: Basically,...$$\begin{align}{\large I} &=\int x^2\,(x^3-6)^{34}\,\mathrm d x \\&= \int \dfrac 13\dfrac{\mathrm d (x^3-6)}{\mathrm d x}\,(x^3-6)^{34}\,\mathrm d x\\ &=\dfrac 13\int u^{34}\,\mathrm d u &&=\dfrac 1{105} u^{35}+{\large C}\text{, but to practice...}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac 13\left(u\cdot u^{34}-\int u\,\mathrm d u^{34}\right)&&\text{integration by parts.}\\&=\dfrac 13\left(u^{35}-\int u\cdot 34 u^{33}\,\mathrm d u\right)\\&=\dfrac 13\left(u^{35}-34\int u^{34}\,\mathrm d u\right)\\&=\dfrac 13 (x^3-6)^{35}-34\,{\large I}\\\therefore~I&=\dfrac{(x^3-6)^{35}}{105}+{\large C}\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp +1 : that is a nice approach.  My only qualm is that when I studied Calculus (in days of yore), the $$I = \frac{1}{3}(x^3 - 6)^{35} - 34I$$ approach was considered an advanced approach that was typically used for a problem like $~\displaystyle \int sin^2(x) ~dx.$  I wanted to present a (pedestrian) approach that was as simple as I could make it.

Comment: Yeah, the exercise looks like a case of "Practice this technique... Ignore the easier way."

Comment: user: "it turned out she hadn't even been taught integration by parts yet, and I was too lazy to look for the other identity of du and just sort of mechanically went after the way I am used to doing this sort of thing. To make it worse the book had other demo problems in this form..."  Those are the OP's words to me.  So nothing begged the question.  Never use a more machinery than needed.  I did not beg the question.

Comment: @amWhy Bizarre.  She hadn't been taught integration by parts yet.  However, the posting's title is: "Where am I going wrong integrating $\int x^2(x^3-6)^{34} dx$ by parts?"  I guess that I was supposed to have the OP and myself simultaneously put our fingertips on our monitors so that I could mind-meld-realize that any use of Integration by Parts should be excluded from the answer.

Comment: By the time you answered, the OP had already accepted the only answer on the previous day, and the OP had clearly commented that the tutee had not even covered integration by parts.  You're "begs the question" comment reveals you do not even know what that means.  In any case, I've alerted mods.  Next time, pay attention to those details, particularly before targeting my post.